# Looking for a similar function to _mm256_load_ps but for a char pointer

Tags: c++, vectorization, intrinsics, avx, avx2

Basically, I want to perform an AND mask over an array of bytes. I know the code would be something like this:

```cpp
char *arr = (char*)_mm_malloc(num_bytes,8);
//fill the array with some values
__m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x12);
for(uint32_t i=0; i<num_bytes; i+=32){
    //load for chars is unknown to me
    __m256i val = _mm256_load_char(arr+i);
    val = _mm256_and_si256 (val, mask);
    //perform extra operations with the result
}
```

But I don't know how to load the packet of 32 bytes safely into an 256 register.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I was too lazy too look for one so I answered instead :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intrinsic for `vmovdqu ymm, [mem]` is `_mm256_loadu_si256( (const __m256i*)any_pointer);`

e.g. **`_mm256_loadu_si256( (const *__m256i) (arr+i) )`**

The aligned-load intrinsic is `_mm256_load_si256();`

See Intel's intrinsic finder https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ or other intrinsics reference where you can find stuff like this.

---

If you're allocating memory on the spot with `_mm_malloc`, ask for 32-byte alignment, not just 8, so you can use aligned loads and be guaranteed not to have any cache-line splits.

---

Intel's integer load/store intrinsics have silly prototypes that require casting the pointer to `__m256i*` even if it's *not* guaranteed to be properly aligned.  Compilers that implement Intel's intrinsics are required to handle this without any undefined behaviour.

(In ISO C++ even *creating* an unaligned pointer without dereferencing it is UB.)

The AVX512 load/store intrinsics finally make this sane, taking `void*` so you don't need all those noisy / ugly casts.

Answer (score 1):

There's `_mm256_loadu_epi8` (the `vmovdqu8` instruction), but that requires AVX512.